# Некорректно работает лайтбокс

Tags: jquery, lightbox

Здравствуйте, я практикуюсь в jQuery и решил для себя написать простенький лайтбокс. Вроде бы легко и даже все получилось, но потом я решил, что изображения, которые больше моего экрана, должны не вылезать за него, а адаптироваться, так и сделал, если изображение больше, то оно уменьшается, но пока оно это делает, происходит немыслимая фигня, вот [пример](http://fedulkin.ru/lightbox.html) работы моего лайтбокса, думаю сами заметите, что не так. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться и довести до ума.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function positionLightboxImage() {

        var img_height = $('#lightbox img').height();
        var window_height = $(window).height();

        if (img_height > window_height) {
            var razn = (img_height - window_height) + 100;

            var new_height = img_height - razn;

            $('#lightbox img').css('height', new_height);
        }

        var Top = ($(window).height() - $('#lightbox img').height()) / 2 - 10;
        var Left = ($(window).width() - $('#lightbox img').width()) / 2;

        $('#lightbox').css({
            'top': Top,
            'left': Left
        }).fadeIn();
    }

    function removeLightbox() {
        $('#overlay, #lightbox').remove();
    }

    $('a.lightbox').click(function () {

        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden')

        $('<div id="overlay"></div>').appendTo('body');

        $('<div id="lightbox"></div>').fadeOut().appendTo('body');

        $('<img/>').attr('src', $(this).attr('href')).load(function () {
            positionLightboxImage();
        }).appendTo('#lightbox');

        $('#overlay').click(function () {
            removeLightbox();
        })

        $('<div id="close"><div>').appendTo('#lightbox');

        $('#close').click(function () {
            removeLightbox();
        })

        return false;
    })
})
```

Comment: Код в студию!

Comment: Ребят, аууу.

Comment: > думаю сами заметите, что не так

А если там много "что не так"? Конкретизируйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: эммм, изображение на глазах у пользователя загружается, и только потом уменьшается(если нужно) и позиционируется по середине экрана.

Comment: По сути нужно, что бы ,блок с картинкой был постоянно скрыт до тех пор, пока изображение не загрузится. В этом случае у меня не получается вычислить размер уже уменьшенного изображения, т.е. получается, но уже в тот момент, когда изображение в полном размере отображается.

Answer (score 1):

При загрузке старницы загрузить большие изображения в фоновом режиме (preload images).